# Bootstrap thumbnail slider : Displaying number of images based on screen

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have created a bootstrap image thumbnail slider.I am displaying four images in the slider  in a normal screen size.

[Demo url:](http://bootply.com/75458)

Now I want to display only one image in the thumbnail slider on the small screen as per responsive.

[image: My current design image]

[image: My required design model]

**Please advice me.I am new bee to the responsive design.**

My code:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="span8">

    <h1>Bootstrap Thumbnail Slider</h1>

    <div class="well">

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
          <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
          <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
          <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
        </div><!--/row-fluid-->
    </div><!--/item-->

    <div class="item">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
            <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
            <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
            <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
        </div><!--/row-fluid-->
    </div><!--/item-->

    <div class="item">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
            <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
            <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
            <div class="span3"><a href="#x" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a></div>
        </div><!--/row-fluid-->
    </div><!--/item-->

    </div><!--/carousel-inner-->

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div><!--/myCarousel-->

    </div><!--/well-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can achieve this solution through CSS alone.  Because the slides of the carousel are the class "item", when this goes to a small screen it will still have 3 item slides, but with 4 vertically stacked thumbnails in each slide (the span3 contents of each slide become stacked with bootstrap responsive classes).  However there are two workarounds.

**OPTION 1 - EASIER**

Have two carousels.  One is the one you have shown, and the other omits the row-fluid and item wrappers, and places item on each span3.  Your original gets the class "hidden-phone" and the new one gets a class "visible-phone".  Additionally, you'll want to omit the slide indicators on the phone version to reduce clutter for many items.  Below I have included a linke to the jsfiddle example.  Just move the vertical frame separator in the middle to the right to resize to phone width (and vice versa).

http://jsfiddle.net/guydog28/tEKg8/

**OPTION 2 - HARDER**

The second option is much more difficult.  If you must only have one carousel, you have to key on the window resize event to see if you are now phone size or above phone size.  Then you actually will have to manipulate the DOM, to make your carousel look like carousel two and then back again on window resize.  So the javascript would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //start the carousel
    $(".carousel").carousel();

    //bind to window resize event to see if we've toggled 
    //between phone and larger
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
          //Phone size, manipulate DOM for phone here
        } else {
          //Not phone size, re-manipulate DOM to get back to original carousel
        }
        //Re-init carousel
        $(".carousel").carousel();
    });
});
```